# How to combine multiple parameters in the media query of foundation 5 interchange?

Tags: zurb-foundation

In [the docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html) says "You can even combine multiple parameters in the media query if need be" but there are no examples.

I tried different ways but can't find anything that works:

```
<div data-interchange="
            [/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], 
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina landscape)],
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina, landscape)],
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina and landscape)],
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina), (landscape)],
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina) and (landscape)],
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina) (landscape)]"></div>
```

Gives me default.jpg

```
<div data-interchange="
            [/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], 
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina)]"></div>

        <div data-interchange="
            [/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], 
            [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (landscape)]"></div>
```

Both gives me retina-landscape-image.jpg, so both conditios are true, the problem is in the syntax for request both conditions.

I know i can make a custom query but if the docs says you can do it, there must by a way.

Comment: Has Interchange ever worked for you? Are you sure you have your Viewport meta in place? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: @Doug Of course it´s working and yes the Viewport is in place, everything is working, i just can't figure it out how to make an interchange rule that combine two queries like the docs says:

"Using Retina Images
You can easily include retina images by using a pixel-density media query for that image. You can even combine multiple parameters in the media query if need be. "

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're currently able to use multiple 'named queries' in a single clause, as I don't believe interchange supports concatenating those. Interchange will take that string then look up the media query associated against that, be it `retina` or `large`, but it currently doesn't process any concept of the AND operator.

```
div data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (retina)]"></div
```

You can however still achieve what you're after, but by putting in the raw media query instead of the 'named query' interchange references against.

From the [Foundation Interchange docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html), you can see the associated media query with both landscape and retina, you just need to concatenate those into a single query.

Retina

```
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)
```

Landscape:

```
only screen and (orientation: landscape)
```

Combining those

```
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (orientation: landscape)
```

I know it's very verbose, but that's retina media queries for you!  Finally, if you were to put this string into interchange..

```
<div data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], [/path/to/retina-landscape-image.jpg, (only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (orientation: landscape))]"></div>
```

You'd be in business!